# American Roth IRA, moving abroad

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, moving

If I set up a Roth IRA in America, can I take out money from it in the future if I'm living outside of the US?

Comment: Are you a US citizen?  Is the move intended to be permanent, or temporary, even if long-term?

Comment: US citizen, long term

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.  At least I had no problems with US accounts while living in Europe, though I was putting money into conventional IRA (and non-retirement accounts), rather than taking it out.